# N2K-C2248TP-1GE question

Tags: cisco-catalyst, layer2, acl, cisco-nexus

We are working with Cisco 2960 and Cisco 4948 switches as our top of rack switches and we want to purchase some N2K-C2248TP-1GE , and connect N2K-C2248TP-1GE to our edge switches, (our edge switches are Arista 7050) so i have some questions:

1. Can N2K-C2248TP-1GE working as standalone switch and in layer 2 mode (only access ports to vlan and such things )
2. Can i assign access lists to ports, specify port security in N2K-C2248TP-1GE?
3. What is the main difference between N2K-C2248TP-1GE and Cisco 4948 ? Thank you.

Comment: Those are not switches. They are fabric extenders for Nexus switches, and they are EoS, with support ending in 2021.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nexus 2000 Series are not switches (see Ron Maupin's comment). They are just what can be considered "remote linecards" of Nexus 5k, 6k, 9k or 7K series switches. You cannot use them without a "mothership" from either of these product ranges.